# Prevent site down when importing data from large XML file WordPress

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, import

It's not a duplicate, I asked on wordpress stackexchange network, but no one answered. So think to migrate here.

## **Scenario :**

I am using WordPress multisite. I have created plugin which imports sample data from theme folder (I have pattern given in plugin which fetches file)

And then I have defined default theme for new blogs, so when someone creates blog and logs into admin panel, plugin starts working.

### **Problem :**

When importing large files (around 15MB or more) which have causes site down until server process that file. Only after success or an error I am able to open site.

Till it shows loading page. And I have checked site from [isup.me](http://isup.me) , it shows site is down.

### Question :

So Is there any other way to work around to prevent site down until it process importing. Or Can I show maintenance mode till successful import operation ?

Comment: Hi, its hard to tell what is going on on your website. File processing and uploading are usually resolved by websites(including WordPress powered websites) without any issues (example if you upload an image ... it doesn't cause down time) so the issue must be in the way your plugin processes the XML file. Can you show some code on how you read data from the XML file and how you process it? also what error do you get when the site is down? do you get a 500 error? an apache error?

Comment: yep, issue is with XML processing. Actually I have used default wordpress Importer with slight modification to automate import when theme is activate. I dont get any error, page just keeps loading no errors at all. Same time when I see database it's importing post, media files etc. after it stops in database, I refresh page and it works as before.

Comment: I have noticed down time by default wordpress importer also.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split your file using [WXR Splitter](https://github.com/suhastech/Wordpress-WXR-Splitter) or gzip it by opening your terminal and typing:

```
gzip /pathtofile/file.xml
```

you can also combine WXR Splitter and gzip that way:

```
gzip /pathtofiles/*
```

this command will zip all your files.